# How to change the z-index of QLineSeries?

Tags: qt, qtcharts

Is there any way to order the z-index for some of my QAbstractSeries added to QChart?
It seems that QChart does it internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Q*Series implementations generate independent `QGraphicsItem`s. These are hidden in the [private implementation](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer) of the series. There is no easy way to access them from the outside.

You could theoretically find them through the scene object (e.g. `QGraphicsScene::items()`). However I don't see a good way to identify them.

For reference, you can find the class in question [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/linechart/linechartitem_p.h.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Zlevel** is set by `QtCharts::ChartItem` that are stored in `QtCharts::ChartPresenter` are hidden in the private part of **QtChart**.  We can get to it by applying the `findChild()` method.

`ChartPresenter` has a method to get its items, but you need to know how you will differentiate them (as a name is assigned to a series.)  I have used the opacity property for this purpose. Keep in mind that when assigning a new **z level**, scenes can be lower (for example *Legend*.)

```
void AppDispatcher::setZLevel(QtCharts::QXYSeries *series)
{
    QtCharts::ChartPresenter* present = series->chart()->findChild<QtCharts::ChartPresenter*>();
    Q_ASSERT(present);

    QList<QtCharts::ChartItem *> items = present->chartItems();

    for(QtCharts::ChartItem * item : items){
        if(item->opacity() == 0.99) { item->setZValue(QtCharts::ChartPresenter::ZValues::SeriesZValue+3); item->setOpacity(1); }
        if(item->opacity() == 0.98) { item->setZValue(QtCharts::ChartPresenter::ZValues::SeriesZValue+2); item->setOpacity(1); }
        if(item->opacity() == 0.97) { item->setZValue(QtCharts::ChartPresenter::ZValues::SeriesZValue+1); item->setOpacity(1); }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I have many series in the chart: how to find exact series in `QList<QtCharts::ChartItem *> items` list? By opacity? Looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old, but I found a solution to this when looking into the QtCharts code, to be specific glxyseriesdata.cpp.

The series is sorted into a map using the series pointer as a key. This map is then iterated for rendering. Setting the z value is thus not really the issue, it is this render ordering.

If you sort your series pointers before passing them to the chart (e.g. by holding them in a vector and using std::sort on it) the render order will be correct.